# How do I handle binary predictor variables in a GLM regression for a species distribution model in R?

Tags: variables, error-handling, binary, glm

I am stuck with creating a Species Distribution Model (SDM) in R.

I have several predictor variables that are in a model matrix together with presence and pseudo absences.
For the continuous predictors (temperature, precipitation, ...) it seems to work, yet the Landuse (habitat) variables are binary and create warnings in the GLM regressions.

I think it is because I'm trying to make a regression with a binary predictor which does not work with polynomial terms.
But I also get the error that the fitted probabilities are close to zero, which makes me question if it is also an issue if the majority of the values are zero (if one habitat type is 1% of the land area in europe this gives me 99% zero values and only 1% of pseudo absences that have a value of 1 in there).
Is this also an Issue?

Would be very grateful for any input as I'm facing a deadline very soon and so far my approaches didn't solve this :(

```
str(model_matrix) 

List of 1
 $ :'data.frame':   58496 obs. of  15 variables:
  ..$ x                          : num [1:58496] 26 24.4 25.8 28.5 28.5 ...
  ..$ y                          : num [1:58496] 70.5 70.5 70.5 70.4 70.4 ...
  ..$ Occurence                  : num [1:58496] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ temp                       : num [1:58496] 0.75 -0.25 0.95 -0.05 0.05 ...
  ..$ precip                     : num [1:58496] 922 896 931 798 766 ...
  ..$ humidity                   : num [1:58496] 64 66 64 68.2 67.8 ...
  ..$ elevation                  : num [1:58496] 179.88 216.3 108.06 1.42 3.2 ...
  ..$ land_cropland              : num [1:58496] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ land_mosaic_cropland_forest: num [1:58496] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ land_broadleaf_forest      : num [1:58496] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ land_needle_forest         : num [1:58496] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 ...
  ..$ land_mixed_forest          : num [1:58496] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ land_shrub_lower5m         : num [1:58496] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 ...
  ..$ land_other                 : num [1:58496] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

The variable 'land_needle_forest' is on a scale 0 = <15%, 1 = 15-40%, 2 = >40% coverage.

```
glm_bse <- glm(form_base, data = model_matrix, family = "binomial")
 SDM_list <- step(glm_bse, directions = 'both', trace = 0)

**Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred**
```

Comment: It would be helpful to have a reproducible example, we can't see what 'form_base' is, but its likely you have separation, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression